# How to find a filename in a string?

Tags: python

I know this might be an already answered question but I searched a lot and I can't seem to find the answer that I'm looking for.

Maybe I am not understanding this..
Here is what I have:

```
myarray = ['image003.jpg@01d36f77.5bf94310', 'image004.jpg@01d36f77.5bf94310']
img = ['image003.jpg', 'test', 'image004.jpg']
```

I am trying to make a loop to check if *img* is in *myarray*.

I tried with `if any(i in img for m in myarrar)` or with a loop that try every element in my array by doing `img.find(myarray[i])`

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: What result do you get from the example you show? I'd expect an error unless i was defined elsewhere.

Comment: If the potential file name is always followed by @, I'd strongly recommend pre-processing myarray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the filenames in `img` *do* exist in `myarray`. However, they exist *in* some of the elements in `myarray`, so you need one more layer of loops.

```
any(fname in s for s in myarray for fname in img)
```

If you need the index that things are present in:

```
for i, s in enumerate(myarray):
    if any(fname in s for fname in img):
        print(i)
```

Comment: how do I iterate for every index in array? Because if I do this `if any(fname in s for s in myarray for fname in img): print('Found')` it would actually print 'Found' only one time right?

Comment: `O(n**2)` complexity the second one there since the `any` loop is run on every element of `myarray`

Comment: @dawg O(n**2) worst case in the first one too. It's not fantastic code if it has to be performant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str.partition](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) in a set comprehension to get the file names (assuming that `@` delimits the filename from some other data in that list of strings):

```
>>> myarray = ['image003.jpg@01d36f77.5bf94310', 'image004.jpg@01d36f77.5bf94310']
>>> {e.partition('@')[0] for e in myarray} 
{'image003.jpg', 'image004.jpg'}
```

Then use a set intersection to test membership against the list `img`:

```
>>> img = ['image003.jpg', 'test', 'image004.jpg']
>>> {e.partition('@')[0] for e in myarray} & set(img)
{'image003.jpg', 'image004.jpg'}
```

If you wanted to have the index of each element in `img` that is in `myarray` you could do:

```
ref={e.partition('@')[0] for e in myarray} 
for i,fn in enumerate(img):
    if fn in ref: print(i,fn)
```

Or, more tersely:

```
>>> [(i,fn) for i,fn in enumerate(img) if fn in {e.partition('@')[0] for e in myarray}]
[(0, 'image003.jpg'), (2, 'image004.jpg')]
```